# Toggle link/button color on new button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to import some customized buttons into a marketing survey application. I would like to set up some buttons styled with CSS and Jquery with some specific functionality.

I need to have the buttons change appearance and stay on the click. I have been able to accomplish this using the code below.

I need help in creating a function that returns any previously selected buttons to the original state while changing the newly selected button to the "clicked" state.

Detailed help would be most appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<a href="#" ID="button">Test Link 1</a><link href="newStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<a href="#" ID="button">Test Link 2</a><link href="newStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(){
       $ (this).toggleClass('clicked');
     });
  });
</script>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
a#button{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
a.clicked#button{
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5c9ab), color-stop(1, #d95936) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e5c9ab 5%, #d95936 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5c9ab', endColorstr='#d95936');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #777777;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've got two elements with the same `id`; this is invalid HTML: an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document. If you want several elements to share the same styles, use a `class`-name instead. That said, I've amended your HTML to:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Test Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Test Link 2</a>
```

As for your jQuery I'd suggest:

```
$('a.button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f36Wq/).

The above assumes the elements will always be siblings; if they may not be:

```
$('a.button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f36Wq/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! =]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(){
         // reset all buttons to un-clicked state
         $('a').removeClass('clicked');
         $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     });
});
```