# Toggle multiple links' button colors on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

My question is similar to [the one Robert Anderson asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753350/toggle-link-button-color-on-new-button-click). That was solved beautifully by David Thomas. Here's that [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f36Wq/1/).

```
$('a.button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('a.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
$(this).addClass('clicked'); 
});
```

But instead of toggling one link color on click, I'd like to toggle three separate colors for three separate link buttons, on each click returning the other links to their default color. Basically exactly what the JS Fiddle does, but toggling three classes rather than one. I'm still a jquery novice and can't make it happen.

More details: these are div links on the page's navbar, so the user isn't navigating to a new page. The idea is that the link button to div1 or div2 will be "lit up" or "colored" on the top nav bar to make clear what section the user is looking at.

Comment: didn't get what you said.. Please share your html code as well.

Comment: Christian Duvall's code should clarify it. That's exactly what I'm talking about. But, for some reason, while his code properly changes the link color, it makes the links themselves useless...

Comment: If you want the links to work, remove `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/f36Wq/26/

Simple way - store the click class you want on a data tag on the link and then retrieve it for use.

```
$('a.button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('a').removeClass('clicked clicked2 clicked3');
   var $this = $(this), cls = $this.data('clckcls');
   $(this).addClass(cls);
});
```

Comment: Even with everything stripped from my stylesheet and the html doc -- leaving just this script, the links, the relevant CSS -- the links don't actually work. I can point them to http://www.google.com and they won't visit the address. But the buttons do change color as they're supposed to. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work at all in IE 11 -- the script that is. So no color changes, but the links function (they'll navigate to other pages).

Comment: Works fine on IE11 for me on W8.